# Python wx session timeoute

Tags: python, timeout, wxpython, wxwidgets

i am trying to write a simple code for timeout a session. my idea is that if user dont interact with the application for 5min, then a function will fireup and kill the application. But if user is active and interact with the application the kill function won't be able to run. Anyone help

my simple wx here

```
import wx

class MyForm(wx.Frame):

    def __init__(self):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, None, wx.ID_ANY, "Timeout",
                          size=(500, 500))

        panel = wx.Panel(self, wx.ID_ANY)
        self.toggleBtn = wx.Button(panel, wx.ID_ANY, "Enter")
        self.toggleBtn.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.onToggle)

    def onToggle(self, event):
        print("you have a action")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = wx.App(False)
    frame = MyForm().Show()
    app.MainLoop()
```

Answer (score 1):

[wx.Timer](https://wxpython.org/Phoenix/docs/html/wx.Timer.html) is what you need.

Start a timer with 60000 ms interval (5 minutes). Bind the timer event to some handler. When the timer shots, close your app in that handler.

If the user makes some action (e.g. moving the mouse, or hitting the keyboard) the timer must be stopped and restarted.

For this you need to bind mouse and keyboard events (and let them to be processed as usual by calling [Skip](https://wxpython.org/Phoenix/docs/html/events_overview.html?highlight=skip)). In these handlers is where you restart the timer.

See, for example, [this wiki](https://wiki.wxpython.org/Timer)

Comment: I don't know if this is possible in Python, but in C++ you can override `wxApp::FilterEvent()` to check for all mouse/keyboard events in a single place -- this is the simplest way to implement inactivity timer.

Comment: i know there must be a way to do this in python. @Ripi2 thanks will give it a try